# One SELECT statement instead of two when they have identical FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
IF( 125 > (SELECT reputation FROM users WHERE id=new.user_id) OR
    1  <> (SELECT active FROM users WHERE id=new.user_id)
) THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You need at least 125rep to give downvote.
                                               And your account have to be active.";
END IF;
```

How can I improve that condition in the `IF` statement?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira `:-)` Yeah It seems ok to me too ... But I think if can be improved. Those two conditions on the `IF` clause have identical both `FROM` and `WHERE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can maybe combine, as follows:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM users 
WHERE id=new.user_id 
AND (reputation < 125 OR (active != 1 OR active IS NULL))
```

Edit: To ignore null active status.

Comment: This query what returns when there isn't any matched row?

Comment: I think it returns NULL

Comment: how that would fit the if to send the signal ?

Comment: Ok, does `IF NULL` execute?

Comment: Lets say, if you have a user row that satisfies the condition. Then you have if(1)..., that definitely executes. Now, in the use case when the user does not satisfy condition, if(null).. will not execute. As I understand if(true or non-zero positive) is only executed and the rest are ignored.

Comment: @Shafizadeh, I edited to handle the null active status. Hope that helps.

Comment: @MSameer Thank you .. Also as a note, you can do that like this: `. . . OR COALESCE(status, 0)  != 1`